# In dita-ot is it possible to integrate into a feature extension for a specific transtype only?

Tags: dita-ot

Specifically, I have a custom dita-ot xhtml plugin which uses the `<feature extension="dita.xsl.xhtml" file="xsl/header.xsl"/>` to integrate into the xhtml pipeline. But this extension is used by the default xhtml output as well. I don't want this. Is there a way to run my extensions only for my own plugin?

A small example (brandheader example from the dita-ot documentation) which demonstrates the described behavior:

plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin id="com.example.brandheader">
    <feature extension="ant.import" file="build.xml" />
    <feature extension="dita.xsl.xhtml" file="xsl/header.xsl"/>
    <transtype name="xhtml-extension" />
</plugin>
```

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="com.example.xhtml.extension" basedir=".">
    <target name="dita2xhtml-extension" depends="dita2xhtml"/>
</project>
```

header.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="gen-user-header">
        <div>
            <img src="https://www.dita-ot.org/images/dita-ot-logo.svg" alt="Example Company Banner"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The customized header appears for the `xhtml` transtype as well as for the `xhtml-extension` transtype.

I searched on stackoverflow for a similar question and I read the dita-ot developer documentation. But I couldn't find an option to enable the extension only for my plugin.

I am happy about any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to override the main XSLT used for processing in your custom XHTML plugin's build file:

```
<target name="dita2xhtml-custom"
      depends="dita2xhtml-custom.init,
               dita2xhtml"/>
<target name="dita2xhtml-custom.init">
  <property name="args.xsl"
        location="${dita.plugin.com.example.xhtml-custom.dir}/custom-main.xsl"/>
</target>
```

and your **custom-main.xsl** would import the xhtml XSLT stylesheet like:

```
<xsl:import href="plugin:org.dita.xhtml:xsl/dita2xhtml.xsl"/>
```

and add your own templates to the **custom-main.xsl** to override templates in  the **dita2xhtml.xsl**.

Comment: That is a wonderful idea. Thank you Radu for taking your time and looking into my question. This answer helps me (hopefully others as well) a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your "header.xsl" XSLT stylesheet will indeed be taken into account for any transformation type extended from the base XHTML one.
But what you could do would be to define in your **plugin.xml** an extension point with the name **dita.conductor.xhtml.param**:
https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/extension-points/all-extension-points.html#all-extension-points__dita.conductor.xhtml.param
Something like this:

```
<feature extension="dita.conductor.xhtml.param" value="params.xml" type="file"/>
```

and the **params.xml** file could contain:

Then in your XSLT stylesheet you define a global xsl:param named "TRANSTYPE" and you should receive on it the value of the transtype from the DITA OT build files, making it possible to take decisions in the custom XSLT templates based on the current transformation type.

Comment: Thanks Radu, that sounds very good if you have to check only for some particular templates if they should be executed. I am looking for a more general solution to avoid this transtype checking in xsl templates. But I guess there is no better solution then. And duplicating the whole xslt plugins is not want I want either.